# Kubernetes liveness probes with query string parameters

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-health-check

I've looked over the documentation and browsed the source, but I can't seem to figure out how to do this. Is there any way to send query string parameters along with the path when implementing a Kubernetes liveness probe?

The string I am sending, which looks something like this:

```
/api/v1?q=...
```

becomes URL-encoded and hits the server as:

```
/api/v1%3fq=...
```

As I have no such route on this particular API, I get a 404, and Kube reaps the pods after the allotted timeout.

Is there any way to define query string parameters to liveness probes and/or trick the URI encoder to allow query string parameters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT: This should now be fixed in Kubernetes 1.3. Thanks to Rudi C for pointing that out.

Liveness probes in Kubernetes v1.2 don't support passing query parameters.

[This Issue](https://github.com/deis/controller/issues/774) in the Deis Controller repo has a good explanation. The gist is that the LivenessProbe.HttpGet.Path is treated as a true URL path (which needs the "?" to be escaped as "%3f").

I've opened a [feature request Issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/29470) against Kubernetes to discuss adding query parameter(s).

As a workaround, you could use an exec livenessProbe that included the query parameters (as long as your container includes something like wget or curl):

```
livenessProbe:
  exec:
    command:
    - wget
    - /api/v1?q=...
```

Comment: This was going to be my backup strategy - we use very stripped down pods that don't include curl/wget, but it seems duty is calling here...thank you for the reply!

Comment: I think Rudi is right. This should now work directly in >= 1.3.0.

Answer (score 3):

Which version are you running? The escaping is a bug that was supposed to be fixed in 1.3:

https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/25064

Not perfect, but it doesn't require additional API fields in the YAML.

Answer (score 0):

If you have some kind of token authorization (via get parameter) and you have health check on root (`service-name/`), you should omit the slash, for example:

```
readinessProbe:
  httpGet:
    path: ?token=${TOKEN}
    port: 80
    scheme: HTTP
```

I had to look through [PR changes](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/25064/files#diff-87a2c77af352e724d42bf3d461fd9b0fR44) to find the way to specify it