# Passing url query parameters in http liveness and readiness probe in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I am trying to configure the HTTP liveness probe as follows:

```
livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
              path: /rest/sends/get?source=mwTESt2VP3Q9M99GNWYvvaLQ1owrGTTjTb #sends API to test address
              port: 4000
              httpHeaders:
                - name: Authorization
                  value: Basic cnBjOnUzSGRlM0xvaWI1SGpEcTFTZGVoQktpU1NBbHE=
          initialDelaySeconds: 60 #wait this period after staring fist time
          periodSeconds: 30  # polling interval
          timeoutSeconds: 30    # wish to receive response within this time period
```

Here, the URL path contains query parameters along with an authentication header (base64 encoding of username:password)

However, I get the following error:

```
 ERROR in app: Exception on /rest/sends/get [GET] (http 500)
```

I checked that this indeed works with status code 200 after logging into the pod

```
curl http://username:password@localhost:4000/rest/sends/get?source=mwTESt2VP3Q9M99GNWYvvaLQ1owrGTTjTb
```

This question is probably similar to this one [Kubernetes liveness probes with query string parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38532286/kubernetes-liveness-probes-with-query-string-parameters?rq=1)

But, according to it, this should have already been fixed. I am using Kubernetes on `Google cloud version: 1.10.7-gke.2` on both master and other nodes.

Am I missing something?

## EDIT

In the server access log, I get the following error

```
10.0.2.1 - - [10/Oct/2018 03:50:45] "GET /rest/sends/get?source=mwTESt2VP3Q9M99GNWYvvaLQ1owrGTTjTb HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Exception on /rest/sends/get [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1988, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1641, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1544, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1639, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1625, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/flask_httpauth.py", line 88, in decorated
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/counterparty_lib-9.55.4-py3.5.egg/counterpartylib/lib/api.py", line 813, in handle_root
    response = handle_rest(rest_path, flask.request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/counterparty_lib-9.55.4-py3.5.egg/counterpartylib/lib/api.py", line 935, in handle_rest
    file_format = flask_request.headers['Accept']
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/werkzeug/datastructures.py", line 1354, in __getitem__
    return _unicodify_header_value(self.environ['HTTP_' + key])
KeyError: 'HTTP_ACCEPT'
```

The server is actually a counterparty-server https://github.com/CounterpartyXCP/counterparty-lib

I am not really sure what the problem is.

Comment: Did you try curl with the actual headers?  `curl -H 'Authorization: Basic cnBjOnUzSGRlM0xvaWI1SGpEcTFTZGVoQktpU1NBbHE' http://localhost:4000/rest/sends/get?source=mwTESt2VP3Q9M99GNWYvvaLQ1owrGTTjTb`? My guess is that your framework doesn't like the header.

Answer (score 1):

I added this header to the request

```
httpHeaders:
    - name: Authorization 
      value: Basic cnBjOnUzSGRlM0xvaWI1SGpEcTFTZGVoQktpU1NBbHE=
    - name: Accept
      value: application/json
```

And now it's working alright.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, the server logs at the end line, in the function [**getitem**](https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/blob/master/werkzeug/datastructures.py) that return "unicodify_header_value" the Class HttpHeaders.Names 'HTTP_ACCEPT' wasn't found, this what was missing in your "**httpHeaders**" config.
nice catch.