# how to avoid encoding in kubernetes http liveness and readiness probes?

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks, amazon-eks

My application has a health check at the endpoint `/service?cmd=watchdog` and when I try to configure a HTTP liveness probe in kubernetes, the above endpoint is getting encoded to utf-8 as it gets applied to the pods (when I do a describe on the pod), the health check is being applies as `/service%3fcmd=watchdog` and that situation does not work for me.

in my deployment.yaml:

```
httpGet:
    path: "/service/?cmd=watchdog"
    port: 8080
```

Is there any way to avoid the encoding / work around this situation?

Comment: I don't see any problem, because if you notice, 0x3f in hex is equal to ?

Comment: Looks very similar to another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38532286/kubernetes-liveness-probes-with-query-string-parameters. Are you using Kubernetes older than 1.3?

Comment: @PaulAnnetts I am on kubernetes version 1.11 and kubctl client 1.13

Comment: I think that extra / character is confusing kubernetes into thinking that the ? is part of a path. Remove the / immediately before the ?, and try that.